# What does "do a once-around" mean?

Tags: meaning, american-english

I've come across it in the 12th episode of the 1st season of *Scrubs*. Here is the context:

> J.D.: What now?
>
> Dr. Cox: Watch the attitude, Gidget, or I won't let you go down to the
> bonfire with the other beach bunnies. Now, I wanna **do a once-around** to
> make sure that everybody's....

Answer (score 1):

I found [the clip you mentioned](https://youtu.be/IXMcBt20jz0?t=79). Given that the doctor proceeds to flip through charts and point at different patients' rooms on the same hospital floor, I assume doing a "once-around" means **going into each patient's room on that floor**, presumably to check on them.